# Setup gitlab pages with own Gitlab instance

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages, gitlab-ee

I just install my own gitlab instance. Bought domain name on GoDaddy and apply A to my ip. Everything works fine. Now how can i setup gitlab pages?

I did everything like official docs, but

Wildcard DNS: A * ip 1hourTTL

pages_external_url 'http://my-domain-name.com'

When i go to Pages i got this: 
[image]

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is `pages_external_url 'http://my-domain-name.com'` all you configured? What kind of installation is you GitLab?

Comment: @SaschaFrinken Yes, this is all what i did. I installed gitlab by using this manual `https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu`

Comment: I think you need at least following setting: `gitlab_pages['enable'] = true`

Comment: @SaschaFrinken I tried, it didnt work

Comment: Did you run the CI to create a public folder with your web content successfully?